# Image size of 747x3360143 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction: when use legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =[0,1,2,3,4]
plt.rcParams.update({"text.usetex": False, "font.family": "serif", "font.serif": ["Palatino"]})

y1 =np.array([e1["E"]/-28486.111])
y2 =np.array([e2["E"]/-28372.065])
y3 =np.array([e3["E"]/-28258.018])
y4 =np.array([e4["E"]/-27687.787])

x1 =np.array([e1["step"]/10000000])
x2 =np.array([e2["step"]/10000000])
x3 =np.array([e3["step"]/10000000])
x4 =np.array([e4["step"]/10000000])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8),frameon=False, dpi=100)
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(x1,y1,"o:",label= '300K',c='blue',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y2,"o:",label= '400K',c='red',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y3,"o:",label= '500K',c='black',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y4,"o:",label= '1000K',c='green',linewidth=0.5)

#corners = ((x1, y1), (x1, y2),(x1, y3),(x1, y4))
#ax.update_datalim(corners)
plt.grid()

plt.tick_params(axis ='both', labelsize =12)
plt.legend(loc="best")

plt.title(r"Variation of the kinetic energy of system",
          fontdict={'family': 'serif',
                    'color':'black',
                    'weight':'bold',
                    'size':18})

plt.xlabel(r'Time(ns)',
           fontdict={'family': 'serif','color':'black','weight':'bold','size':16})

plt.ylabel(r"$\mathbf{E}$/$\mathbf{E_0}$",fontsize=16)
ax.set_xticks(x)
plt.savefig("energy.png")

#plt.show()

ValueError: Image size of 747x3360143 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

Hello everyone, when I validate this code for a representation of 4 graphs and I put the legend of each graph, I have an error of size. I have attached the output image that I have with the error

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide us the shape of `x1` and `y1`, the like of `print(x1.shape, y2.shape)` ? It seems that the the first plot, where the label is `"300K"`, is producing a LARGE number of curves.  If you really are plotting so many curves, I'd suggest to use two plot commands for each data set, firs plot a single curve with the corresponding label, then plot, using the same color, all the remaining ones WITHOUT the label, so that eventually the legend will show a single key for each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of your legend. I'm not sure why it is functioning like in the image you posted - I could not re-create that behavior with your code. I would recommend trying to comment out the legend and see if your code works. You may find the matplotlib documentation [legend tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) helpful.

If you can provide more info about the e1, e2, e3, and e4 values it would help simulate and troubleshoot more effectively.

A couple of other comments:

1. You don't need the line ax = plt.gca(), it is already defined as such
2. If e1['E'] and others like it are pandas series or numpy arrays, then you don't need to re-initialize the arrays for each variable

I attempted to simulate some lines like yours and implemented in your code.

[image]

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =[0,1,2,3,4]
plt.rcParams.update({"text.usetex": False, "font.family": "serif", "font.serif": ["Palatino"]})

#e appears to be some large array
#simulate with some large array
e = np.linspace(0.001, 4, 1000)
x1 = x2 = x3 = x4 = e
y1 = np.log(e)
y2 = np.log(e) + 0.5
y3 = np.log(e) + 1
y4 = np.log(e) + 1.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8),frameon=False, dpi=100)

ax.plot(x1,y1,"o:",label= '300K',c='blue',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y2,"o:",label= '400K',c='red',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y3,"o:",label= '500K',c='black',linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x1,y4,"o:",label= '1000K',c='green',linewidth=0.5)

plt.grid()
plt.tick_params(axis ='both', labelsize =12)
plt.legend(loc="best")

title   = plt.title(r"Variation of the kinetic energy of system", fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
x_label = plt.xlabel(r'Time(ns)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
y_label = plt.ylabel(r"$\mathbf{E}$/$\mathbf{E_0}$",fontsize=16)
#ax.set_xticks(x)
```